# SQL query row_number() over partition by query result return wrong for some case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two SQL Server tables:

`FormSchema` columns

```
SchemaId, SchemaName, Tenant
```

`RoleTable` columns

```
SchemaId, RoleId, RoleName, Tenant
```

Expected result (includes below three conditions):

- select row in result where individual SchemaName exist in Tenant 'A'
- select row in result where individual SchemaName exist in Tenant 'All'
- If duplicate/same SchemaName exist in Tenant 'A' and 'All' both then select row in result which belong to Tenant 'A'.

Query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         fs1.schemaid, fs1.schemaName, ar1.roleId, ar1.roleName, ar1.tenant,
         rn = row_number() over (partition by fs1.schemaName
                                 order by case when ar1.tenant = 'ALL' then 2 else 1 end, ar1.tenant)
     from   
         RolesTable ar1
     full outer join 
         FormSchema fs1 on ar1.SchemaId = fs1.SchemaId) as t3
where 
    rn = 1
    and Tenant in ('B', 'All')
```

Please see the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3492f1af9cfbab695e292c6b0dad7b33) for table, records, and expected and actual result.

The issue I am facing like while giving Tenant as 'B' expected result is wrong but instead if i use 'A' expected result is correct.

Expected result for 'B' is wrong** because it's not satisfying the following:

- If duplicate/same SchemaName exist in Tenant 'B' and 'All' both then select row in result which belong to Tenant 'B'.i.e. SchemaName 'Car'. So query should select in result 'B' 'Car' row.

Expected Result for 'B':

```
SchemaId   RoleId                                   RoleName    Tenant
--------------------------------------------------------------------
'664'      '40ecca83-7fd9-4d63-9f56-c7a48442d844'   '#Test-1'   'B'
'456'      '40ecca83-7fd9-4d63-9f56-c7a48442d844'   '#Test-1'   'B'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your expected result for 'B' and explain why your current result is wrong.

Comment: i have updated both in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the condition for the `Tenant` from the outer query inside the subquery:

```
select * 
from (
  select fs1.schemaid, fs1.schemaName, ar1.roleId, ar1.roleName, ar1.tenant,
         row_number() over (
           partition by fs1.schemaName
           order by case when ar1.tenant = 'ALL' then 2 else 1 end, ar1.tenant
         ) rn
  from RolesTable ar1 full outer join FormSchema fs1
  on ar1.SchemaId= fs1.SchemaId
  where ar1.Tenant in (?, 'All')
) as t3
where rn = 1
```

Replace `?` with `'A'` or `'B'`.

Also, it is not clear why you are doing a `FULL` join instead of a `LEFT` join.
If you want in the results unmatched rows from both tables, then may be you should use `COALESCE()`:

```
where coalesce(ar1.Tenant, fs1.Tenant) in (?, 'All')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf7688184b81d81934c54c9d54d2ec78).

Answer (score 1):

I find the logic a bit hard to follow.  And I don't understand why you are using a `full join` when an `inner join` does the work.

However, I think what you need to do is filter in the subquery:

```
select * 
from (select fs1.schemaid, fs1.schemaName, ar1.roleId, ar1.roleName, ar1.tenant ,
             row_number() over (partition by fs1.schemaName
                          order by case when ar1.tenant = 'ALL' then 2 else 1 end, ar1.tenant) as seqnum
      from RolesTable ar1 join
           FormSchema fs1
          on ar1.SchemaId= fs1.SchemaId
      where ar1.Tenant in ('B', 'All')
     ) t3
where seqnum = 1 ;
```

Comment: I am not sure but i am thinking Reason for using full outer joins is
1.May be some row belong to Tenant 'A' only
2.May be some row belong to Tenant 'B' only
3.May be some row belong to Tenant 'A' and 'B' both

Comment: @r08 . . . If that is the case, the OP should be providing data that demonstrates that.  However, the table `FormSchema` would appear to be the entity that defines `SchemaId` and an `inner join` -- or perhaps `left join` -- is all that is necessary.

Comment: No,full outer join is not necessary.i thought all result might be need to select so i kept...
what is the best practices to achieve above expected result...as you mention bit hard to follow?